# Использование WebSocket на андроид

Tags: websocket, android, javascript, java

Всем добрый вечер.
Мой вопрос:
Мне необходимо сконектится с WebSocket на андроид. На сегодня сервер работает как эхо, то есть возвращает посланное, и мне бы хотелось проверить это через мое андроид приложение. Я прочел пару статей на эту тему, но пока ничего не получилось! Так вот чтобы открыть соединение с сокетом на JavaScript это делается так new Websocket('ws://ofs.ft-ru.ru:8080').
Как мне это сделать на андроид, и при этом отправить и получить что нибудь?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну например, есть готовый проект на github [android-websockets](https://github.com/koush/android-websockets). Или вот ещё один [AutobahnAndroid](http://autobahn.ws/android).

Comment: Спасибо! Но с этими библиотеками я уже знаком! Как их использовать? Мне просто срочно нужно проверить сервер через андроид, а за час я точно с этими библиотеками не разберусь!

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо все получилось! Поспешь - людей насмешишь. Вот и я! Работает!