# Как на андроид реализовать работу с Websocket.IO Node.js

Tags: node.js, java, android, websocket

Всем добрый вечер!

Необходимо реализовать клиентское приложение которое могло бы отсылать и принимать сообщения от сервера работающем на `Node.js` посредством `Websocket.IO`.

Нашел несколько примеров и даже библиотек по работе с Websoket.IO на андроид, но самое ужасное я не могу присобачить библиотеки к Андроид приложению, т.к. они `Java` (имею ввиду не андроид библиотеки).

Ссылки на те ресурсы по которым я ориентировался:

- [socket.io-java-client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client)
- [socket.io-java-client and node.js - Error while handshaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264051/socket-io-java-client-and-node-js-error-while-handshaking)
- [Nodejs socket.io server connect with Android but don't send messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536368/nodejs-socket-io-server-connect-with-android-but-dont-send-messages)

Может кто нибудь сталкивался с данной проблемой? Главный вопрос как подключить данную библиотеку к моему приложению?

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо искать по запросу "Websocket android". То, что на серверной стороне Node.js, не должно влиять на клиентскую сторону.

Вот, например: [Использование WebSocket на андроид](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/242438/javascript-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-websocket-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4)

Comment: А Вы случаем не сравнивали автора этого вопроса и того?)

Comment: Влиет еще как!

Comment: Нда, я и подумать не мог, что получивший (вроде бы) содержательный ответ будет спрашивать еще раз.

Есть несколько вариантов спецификации WebSocket - см. http://www.quickiwiki.com/ru/WebSocket

Узнайте, какого варианта придерживается Node.js, и ищите соответствующую библиотеку на Андроиде.

Comment: Я обращу Ваше внимание, что я даже нашел такую библиотеку и дал ссылку на нее в своем вопросе. Понимаю лучше написать ответ не читая вопроса! Это первый признак высококлассного программиста-экстрасенса!

Answer (score 1):

Компилируете *.jar файл. Кладёте в папочку lib. Добавляете магическую строчку в build.gradle:

`compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

Всё.

Я лично использовал эту бибилиотеку https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket в связке с Node JS  WS  лтсюда https://github.com/websockets/ws

Maven/Gradle не доверяйте - там версии 2х годичной давности